# Updating jQuery version Volusion

Tags: jquery, volusion

Does anyone know how to update the version of jQuery being used on a Volusion site? Volusion runs a lot of ASP code that's server side so it's generated dynamically but currently they are running:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's way outdated and preventing me from doing a lot of things. Just curious if anyone knows of a workaround since I can't find out how to edit it and Volusion support can't give me an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the jQuery version as it is hardcoded by Volusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can run multiple versions of jquery on a single page, I have to do it all the time on volusion sites.

Read this post from 4 years ago for http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

Hope it helps!

Comment: @MillerMedia Matt! I just realised that this was probably posted before we met while we were both working for Karen Mollison! I just saw this 5 years later haha. Hope all is well!